# Slow performance for Update Self Join for massive data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my tblAccount, there are 3 indexes. Clustered indexes are "Date, Accnumber, CifNum". while non-clustered are "ID1" and "ID2". I used inner self join to detect what needs to be determined as an error, but there is a huge amount of data and the joining takes very long, causing slow performance. What can be done to avoid this?

I wanna check when row1 ID1 is same with row2 ID2, it would be an error.

```
UPDATE t SET ErrorCode = 'Same value of ID1 ID2'
FROM tblAccount t WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblAccount t2 WITH (NOLOCK)
ON t.Date = t2.Date
AND t.CifNum = t2.CifNum
AND t.ID2 = t2.ID1
WHERE t.Date = '20171231'
```

Below is when there was different ID1 or ID2 detected for the same CifNum and Date.

```
UPDATE t SET t.ErrorCode = (CASE WHEN t.ID1 <> t2.ID1 OR t.ID2 <> t2.ID2 THEN 'Different ID1 or ID2' ELSE NULL END)
FROM tblAccount t WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblAccount t2 WITH (NOLOCK)
ON t.Date = t2.Date 
AND t.CifNum = t2.CifNum
AND (t.ID1 <> t2.ID1 OR t.ID2 <> t2.ID2 )
WHERE t.Date = '20171231'
```

Would a group by help in this case as below?

```
UPDATE t SET ErrorCode = 'Same value of ID1 ID2'
FROM tblAccount t WITH (NOLOCK) 
inner join (select cifnum, ID1, ID2, Date from tblAccount WHERE Date ='20171231' group by cifnum, ID1, ID2, Date) t2
ON t.Date = t2.Date
AND t.CifNum = t2.CifNum
AND t.ID2 = t2.ID1
WHERE t.Date = '20171231'
```

Comment: [Stop](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) using NOLOCK everywhere, it is not a magic "go fast" button. [Especially](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/) with DML statements!

Comment: You can probably rewrite the query as `INTERSECT` or `EXISTS` but can't say about performance.

Comment: Maybe I get this wrong, but is there a reason not to use `Accnumber` in your `JOIN` condition?

Comment: Your clustered index consists of three columns (with `Accnumber` on the second place). Might help to introduce a separate index onto `CifNum`...

Comment: @Shnugo if it is having a clustered on this, is it best to use them all at once in a join? because i wanted to check on the ids of the same cifnum only. one cifnum might have multiple different accnum?  and if i were to add on another separate index onto CifNum, will it give impact to other statements that are currently using the existing clustered index?

Comment: @whoami. The Clustered index is the *physical* order of your rows. You can think of it as the physical table itself. This is *grouped sorted* after the Date, then then account number and finally the CifNum. You can use the first column, or the first and the second, or all three of them, but not the first and the third... An additional index should make most reading faster, but needs space and additional action on update, insert and delete. The optimizer is really good at choosing the best strategy...

Comment: if thats the case, can i inner join on date, accnum, cifnum. then group then by cifnum and date to choose which to update?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to update same values

```
UPDATE t SET ErrorCode = 'Same value of ID1 ID2'
FROM tblAccount t 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tblAccount t2 
        WHERE t.Date = t2.Date
        AND t.CifNum = t2.CifNum
        AND t.ID2 = t2.ID1)
AND t.Date = '20171231'
```